# Proper SVG markup for external files to be loaded with Snap.svg

Tags: svg, snap.svg

So here's the deal, I'm making some experiments with **SVG** and **Snap.svg**. I have an external **SVG** file, `logo.svg`, that was created with Adobe Illustrator, here's the markup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="161.875px" height="144px" viewBox="0 0 161.875 144" enable-background="new 0 0 161.875 144" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="#006098" points="144,144 27,144 57,0 144,0 144,54 161.875,72 144,90 "/>
<polygon fill="#00416A" points="57,144 0,144 0,0 87,0 "/>
<polygon fill="#98D5E9" points="72,57 72,27 87,27 117,27 117,57 117,72 117,94.5 117,117 87,117 87,94.5 57,94.5 57,72 87,72 
    87,57 "/>
<polygon fill="#288DC1" points="57,57 75.125,57 81.375,27 57,27 27,27 27,57 27,72 27,94.5 27,117 57,117 57,94.5 67.313,94.5 
    72,72 57,72 "/>
</svg>
```

I want to use this example and explore **Snap.svg** animations, so I'm loading it this way:

```
(...)
var s = Snap(element);
Snap.load('/images/logo.svg', function(f) {
  s.append(f);
});
(...)
```

But for this to work my `element` must be a `<svg>`, so I end up with a `<svg>` inside a `<svg>`:

```
<svg logo-svg>
  <desc>Created with Snap</desc>
  <defs></defs>
  <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0px" y="0px" width="161.875px" height="144px" viewBox="0 0 161.875 144" enable-background="new 0 0 161.875 144" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
  <polygon fill="#006098" points="144,144 27,144 57,0 144,0 144,54 161.875,72 144,90 "></polygon>
  <polygon fill="#00416A" points="57,144 0,144 0,0 87,0 "></polygon>
  <polygon fill="#98D5E9" points="72,57 72,27 87,27 117,27 117,57 117,72 117,94.5 117,117 87,117 87,94.5 57,94.5 57,72 87,72 
    87,57 "></polygon>
  <polygon fill="#288DC1" points="57,57 75.125,57 81.375,27 57,27 27,27 27,57 27,72 27,94.5 27,117 57,117 57,94.5 67.313,94.5 
    72,72 57,72 "></polygon>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Somehow I fill this is a bit messy, is this correct? Or there's a better way to load external **SVG** files?

Comment: I think the principle is fine, ie often you may load quite a few SVGs and they need to be inside another SVG. Plus Snap.load is actually taking a document fragment which needs appending to something. So to me it makes sense, but if you can highlight certain problems you are facing because of this, it could be there is a workaround.

Comment: Thanks @Ian, I wanted to make sure that I was doing thing right, since I'm very new to this. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to give the same width and height of my external *svg* file to the parent element `<svg>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the principle is fine, ie often you may load quite a few SVGs and they need to be inside another SVG.

Plus Snap.load is actually taking a document fragment which needs appending to something. So to me it makes sense, but if you can highlight certain problems you are facing because of this, it could be there is a workaround.

I'm just going to post an example to adjust the main paper to the new svg which could be used...

```
var s = Snap("#svgpaper"); 
var bird = Snap.load("bird.svg", function ( loadedFragment ) { 
            var b = s.append( loadedFragment );
            var bbox = b.getBBox();
            var vbox = bbox.x + " " + bbox.y + " " + bbox.width + " " + bbox.height;                                           
            s.attr({ viewBox: vbox });  
 } );
```

testing example [here](http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-load-focus.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian! Since you answered my question with the comment I edited your answer and included it for future reference, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Fine with me. Glad its helped!